# PHP Write To A file Overwriting Only Selected Sections

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I am trying to dynamically write to a css file. The file already has some content in it, and I want dynamically generated css rules to append to the end of the file.

However, my code always overwrite the file deleting all the previous data, but when I use the `FILE_APPEND` flag. The problem is that, when I write the file again, it appends the data again at the bottom duplicating the existing rules.

Here is the final code I landed into after a lot of trial and error:

```
function mytheme_save_page_css( $post_id ) {

    $margin = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_margin', true );
    $padding = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_padding', true );
    $bgcol = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_bg_col', true );

    $newmargin = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pagemargin'];
    $newpadding = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pagepadding'];
    $newbgcol = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pagebg'];

    if ( $margin != $newmargin || $padding != $newpadding || $bgcol != $newbgcol ) {

        $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lib/css/sections/style.css';
        $css = 'header{margin:'.$newmargin.';padding:'.$newpadding.';background-color:'.$newbgcol.';}';

        file_put_contents($file, $css, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_margin', $newmargin );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_padding', $newpadding );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_page_bg_col', $newbgcol );

}
```

Is there any way to replace only those rules instead of just duplicating them again and again (and creating a separate CSS file)?

Comment: You could use regular expressions to search and replace the updated values. But I'd recommend writing a new file every time. It reduces the risk of having unexpected results (f.e. what happens if someone edits the file by hand and duplicates a selector?).

Answer (score 0):

This is a lose-lose situation ... as php should know what to keep, and what to change. That implies a parsing of the css-content, which I guess is outside your scope.

My solution would be to have a separate css-file, where all the 'replaceable' css-rules live, and where you replace everything on every write.

Alternatively, you could use a special `comment`-delimiter (a unique string) around the rules you want replaced, in the main css-file, and then search for that delimiter ... keeping everything outside, and replacing everything inside. This is a bit more complicated, but doable.

*PS: You should be aware of semi-racing-conditions, where a client requests your file, while it is EX-locked ... the lock won’t (as far as i know) prevent a simple client-requested serving ... just a heads up.*

Comment: Or two css files, a 'base css' file that never changes and an 'output css file' that combines the base with the custom generated one every time.